# Warning when restoring from seed

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed

When I restore a wallet from a standard 25 word English seed:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet
```

I get the following warning:

> You had been using a deprecated version of the wallet. Please use the new seed that we provide.

However the "new" list of mnemonic words shown by the wallet is the same as what I entered.

**Is there something wrong with my seed?**

Answer (score 3):

If I remember well there was a minor bug in displaying the new one. Try using the command `seed` to show it again, it should be different. Note that both old and new seed will encode to the same private key.

The difference is that old one was just a random number which would have to be 'normalized' to a valid private key. Now, your seed **is** your private key. More in-depth explanation here: [Why did monero-wallet-cli restore the same wallet with different mnemonic seeds?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1831/why-did-monero-wallet-cli-restore-the-same-wallet-with-different-mnemonic-seeds)

Answer (score 3):

Your seed was probably made using the old english word list, and the new seed is made with the current list instead. The old list has several infelicities, such as duplicate word prefixes.