# How does inner key generation work?

Tags: viewkey, privatekey, spend-key

As far as I know electrum-words generate private spend key.
private view key is `Keccak_256(private spend key)`. So how is it possible that if I calculate library function Keccak_256 (Crypto++) on my private spend key, I get something different then my actual private view key?

Comment: What you input? A number or a character sting?

Comment: My program computes the correct value of Keccak_256. Keccak_256(0x4040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040) == Keccak_256("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@") == 0xf5f98609c9914be409c9060f871f0797dd98d63f0d2ca298810b42a919a0b12f
You can verify it [here](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html)...
[Monero key calculator](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) outputs different value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an additional step performed, called "normalization". It's just a modulo operation with **l**. See [sc_reduce32 ... is it really supposed to be that complicated?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3567/sc-reduce32-is-it-really-supposed-to-be-that-complicated)

Oh and note that mnemonic is decoded to seed and then:

`spendkey = sc_reduce(seed)`

`viewkey = sc_reduce(keccak(spendkey))`

New versions of wallets roll a random 256bits, normalize it and use that as seed so the below holds true:

`seed == sc_reduce(seed)`

See [Why did monero-wallet-cli restore the same wallet with different mnemonic seeds?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1831/why-did-monero-wallet-cli-restore-the-same-wallet-with-different-mnemonic-seeds)