# What is the importance of the 25th word in a mnemonic seed?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, check-sum

Is this additional word important for some reason? And should I need to make sure to write it down or is that optional?

Comment: You can recreate the last word but if you don't know how to do it, it's probably best to keep all 25 words. See also http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/874/what-is-the-checksum-at-the-end-of-a-mnemonic-seed and http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/why-one-word-is-found-two-times-in-each-seed