# mnemonic seed recovery tool - missing word location unknown

Tags: mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery

I used [this tool](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3992/1414) on an offline machine to recover just one word (not two) successfully without [knowing the position of the missing word](https://github.com/JollyMort/xmr.llcoins.net/blob/master/README.md) by manually moving the word *missing* until I found a match.

> Type your mnemonic into 1., and write *missing* in place of the word(s) you lost.

Because the search process was quick I was able to find my answer quickly. Is there a way the process (of choosing locations for the missing words) can be automated so that people missing two words instead of one can avoid a more tedious process of finding the correct placement for the missing words?