# Monero Gui didn't create .keys file for wallet, it crashed, wasn't able to restore wallet, is it lost?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, security, daemon

My Monero Gui was freezing every 10 seconds when I clicked on it so I just killed the process, after trying to reopen multiple times I killed the `monerod` daemon process as well

When opening again the gui, I tried to locate the wallet file which is only named `walletname`, there was no .keys file created, it doesn't even appear in the gui explorer so I have to type the name manually and try to open

After trying to restore through this it gives me an error:

```
Couldn't open wallet: file not found "C:\Users\Documents\Monero\wallets\walletname\walletname.keys"
```

I wrote my mnemonic down to a paper when I created the wallet but apparently I only have 23 words and it's not working. Did I copy it right?

Is there any other way to restore this wallet? Because I had just made a big deposit there.

Comment: Does your username contain a special (non-ASCII) character (e.g. é, ø, â, Ö)?

Answer (score 1):

You can restore a wallet by either using the .keys file + its password or the 25 word mnemonic seed.  There is, unfortunately, no other way.

The wallet files are by default, located in Documents\Monero (on Windows). Have a look there and see if you can't find any files there.

If you only wrote 23 of the 25 words, something went wrong when you were copying it down.  If you know which words (the last two perhaps b/c you were interrupted?) that are missing, you could brute force the password, but you're looking at 1616<sup>2</sup> = 2,611,456 different possible seeds.  That's only if you know where the words are.  If you're not sure which words you've missed, you're looking at a much larger number.
Note that if you're actually only missing the last two words specifically, that would be the best of all possible worlds as the last word is a checksum of all the previous words.

If you'd like to get cracking at your money, have a look at the [mnemonic seed list](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/mnemonics/english.h) and info about the [monero check sum](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/874/what-is-the-checksum-at-the-end-of-a-mnemonic-seed).

Comment: unfortunately Monero GUI didn't create any .keys file. I'm not sure how that happened or if it was because it crashed but it definitely didn't create any .keys file, only the walletname file with no extension.

Comment: hmm.  I haven't looked into the codebase but thought the walltname file (w/o extension) was just an analyzation of the chain from wallet inception height through present block, looking for tx that would affect your wallet's balance.  If that file actually gets created before the wallet.keys file does, sounds to me like that should be changed.  (Hell, you shouldn't be able to even view a receive address w/o the .keys file being saved).  If that's the case, i would suggest opening up an issue on github.